# Single Linked List that implements push and pop - seg fault

Tags: c, linked-list, stack

I'm looking over some old code to write a program (in C) that creates push and pop methods similar to a stack for a singly linked list. I'm currently getting a segmentation fault and can't figure out the issue.

The input for any pushes will be single characters, here's an input example:
push ;
push g
push .
pop
push -

**Code (commented out some things that were causing errors):**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    char data;
    struct node* next;
}*top = NULL;

void push(char c);
char pop();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char* p1;
char p2;
FILE *fp = NULL;
fp = fopen(argv[2], "r");

loop:
    while (!feof(fp)) 
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%s", &p1);

        while (strcmp(&p1,"push") == 0) 
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%s", &p2);
            printf("%s\n", &p2); 
            // push(&p2);
            fscanf(fp,"%s", &p1);
            if (strcmp(&p1,"pop") == 0) 
            {
                //pop();
                 fscanf(fp,"%s", &p1);
            }
        }

        while (strcmp(&p1,"pop") == 0) 
        {
            //pop();??
            fscanf(fp,"%s",&p1);
            if (strcmp(&p1,"push") == 0) 
            {
                fscanf(fp,"%s",&p2);
                printf("%s\n",&p2); 
                // push(&p2);
            }
            goto loop;
         }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;   
}

void push(char c) 
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = c;
    temp->next = top;
    top = temp;
}

char pop() 
{
    struct node *temp = top;
    char data = temp->data;
    top = top->next;
    free(temp);
    return data;
}
```

**Current Warnings:**

```
stack.c: In function âmainâ:

stack.c:24:3: warning: format â%sâ expects argument of type âchar *â, but argument 3 has type âchar **â [-Wformat]

stack.c:26:3: warning: passing argument 1 of âstrcmpâ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

/usr/include/string.h:143:12: note: expected âconst char *â but argument is of type âchar **â

stack.c:31:4: warning: format â%sâ expects argument of type âchar *â, but argument 3 has type âchar **â [-Wformat]

stack.c:32:4: warning: passing argument 1 of âstrcmpâ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

/usr/include/string.h:143:12: note: expected âconst char *â but argument is of type âchar **â

stack.c:35:5: warning: format â%sâ expects argument of type âchar *â, but argument 3 has type âchar **â [-Wformat]

stack.c:39:3: warning: passing argument 1 of âstrcmpâ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

/usr/include/string.h:143:12: note: expected âconst char *â but argument is of type âchar **â

stack.c:42:4: warning: format â%sâ expects argument of type âchar *â, but argument 3 has type âchar **â [-Wformat]

stack.c:43:4: warning: passing argument 1 of âstrcmpâ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

/usr/include/string.h:143:12: note: expected âconst char *â but argument is of type âchar **â
```

Comment: Your uses of `p1` and `p2` is totally wrong, and that is the reasons of your segmentation fault.

Comment: I see, changing those and looking at the accepted types versus what I'm providing. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warnings already tell you, what to do. The pointers the functions expect `char*`, and the pointer you pass `&p1` aka `char**` are of different type. To fix this you must use `p1` instead of `&p1`.

But you have another issue, you use `p1` before it is initialized. This leads to segmentation faults too, because the pointer points nowhere and the functions `printf` or `strcmp` try to access the content there.

This means in the case of `fscanf`, you must allocate memory, where the content can be stored, see [`malloc`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc). Same goes for `p2`, of course.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks very much. Sorry for my noob understanding of C!

Answer (score 1):

first of all p1 hav't any memory to point to.  secondly you are passing &p1 to fscanf but fscanf expects it to be char * and &p1 has char ** since you have deplared it to be char *p1 and char *p2.what i ll suggest is you do the coding from scratch instead of coping the code coz this code has many intax errors.and probably your segmentation fault is because of the fscanf() itself coz you are passing argument of wring type.